# How does python know when to stop the for loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

1st time programming in python How does python know  when to stop the for loop?
Like the for does not have a matching end correct? so how does it know what is part of the loop and what is not?
Apologies if this is stupid question I could not find the answer

Comment: Indentation, like everything else in Python. If it's indented, it's a part of whatever above is indented less.

Comment: Python relies on indentation for code blocks, so it knows where a loop's code block ends based on what code is and isn't indented.

Answer (score 1):

Python relies heavily on indentation

```
# The code below prints 0-4, sees that the next for line is not indented, doesn't read it
for x in range(5):
    print(x)

# there are other methods of breaking a python loop
for x in range(6):
    print(x)
 if x == 5:
         # break the loop
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

well for x in range(5) means itll go up to 5 times(ya already knew that) but thats because it says "ok ill do this until x is equal to 5 while" keep in mind that x gets +1 bigger per itteration. try typing:

```
for x in range(25):
    print(x)
```

now it will say 123456789 etc.

Comment: Thanks but I was asking how does it know what is and isn't part of the loop without an end for